# Limiting Android minsdk to 4x & up using Intel XDK development environment

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

I'm wanting to limit the android users (on google play store, etc.) to android 4.x & up.

I'm using the Intel XDK environment to develop an android app.  It's being built with the cordova 3.x build process (in XDK) and I've setup the intelxdk.config.xml file as follows below.

The min sdk version is:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
```

However when I set it up in the Google Play Store it says that it will be compatible with android 1.6 & up?

I'm wondering if I'm missing something?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.  The full android config is below:

```
<!-- Android specific configuration -->
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false"/>
<preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0xffffffff"/>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" /> 
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />


<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="android-permission" value="GET_TASKS" />
<preference name="android-permission" value="VIBRATE" />
<preference name="android-signed" value="true" />   

<!-- 
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="<LOCATION>" />
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="<INPUTMODE>" />
-->
```

Comment: Check what you have in AndroidManifest.xml (sorry I'm not familiar with xdk just cordova so I can't guide you on where it is). With pure cordova projects we have to manually update this file for this kind of options.

Comment: Thanks for the input on it ;)  If I understand correctly though (& I might be wrong) the intelxdk.config.xml is the equivalent of the AndroidMainifest.xml  My understanding of it is that you set the minSdkVersion & the android-targetSdkVersion values & that takes care of it.  Adjusting minSdkVersion from "N" (which defaults to value "10" for android) to "14" did reduce the supported devices list by ~1000 but it still say's "supports 1.6 & up at the bottom of the store page.  Thanks though, I'll check the AndroidMainfest.xml info though ;)

Comment: seems intelxdk.config.xml is equivalent of cordova config.xml. config.xml misses some capabilities that seem to have been added to intelxdk.config.xml but anyway when you build, a AndroidManifest.xml is updated from what you have in your config, so your changes should be reflected in this file (it's the only file Android knows)

Answer (score 0):

I just got a message from the Intel XDK group -- they suggest upgrading to the latest (build 1199) version of XDK where the build doesn't require manually creating the intelxdk.config.xml file.  I don't understand exactly what that fixed, but it resolved it ;)